Oracle 19 Upgrade TIMEZONE_VERSION
I upgraded Oracle 19 TIMEZONE_VERSION from 32 to 36.
I used this tutorial https://www.br8dba.com/upgrade-timezone-version/
If I connect with sqlplus / as sysdba and run SELECT * FROM v$timezone_file; it returns me version 36.
If after that I create a new database and run SELECT * FROM v$timezone_file; on it and it returns me version 32.
What should I do to upgrade the new database as well?
Thanks
